# Session affinity function in Google Load Balancer

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using the session affinity function in Google Load Balancer.
However I have the problem as below.

When gave stress A-WEB Server, access server changed to B-WEB Server. According to LB parameter, when CPU utilization over 80%, changing access server. But I configured session affinity for keeping access.

**I would like to keep access same server, am I missing something?**

*Architecture*

Building 2 WEB Server with DB under the LB to search the data about some information.

*Configuration LB Parameter*

- Balancing mode : Utilization
- Maximum CPU utilization : 80% (default)
- Capacity : 100% (default)
- Session affinity : generated cookie
- Affinity coolie TTL : 1800
- Connection request headers : 300
- Security policy : None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Losing [session affinity](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#losing_session_affinity) regardless of type can occur (i.e client IP affinity or [cookie affinity](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#generated_cookie_affinity)) with the instance in the following scenarios.

1. Session affinity will not work if the target instance becomes unhealthy, Affinity is lost as the session is moved to a healthy instance. so you should not assume perfect affinity unless all the bakends are healthy.
2. It has little meaningful effect on UDP traffic, because a [session for UDP](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#session_affinity) is a single request and response.
3. If the instance group runs out of capacity, and traffic has to be routed to a different zone breaking affinity.
4. Configuring backend service with [auto-scaling](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#instance_groups) adds instances to, or removes instances from, the instance group. In either case, the backend service reallocates load, and the target may move affecting session affinity.
5. The balancing mode is set to [CPU utilization](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#load_distribution_algorithm), which may cause your computed capacities across zones to change, sending some traffic to another zone within the region. Check at stress condition if the server % CPU utilization exceeds the threshold level or not.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I could improved this problem.

After referred to No.3 comments and [session affinity details](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#losing_session_affinity), I changed from CPU utilization to RPS.

Probably I consider, when I searched a lot of data, gave stress to WEB server. And then, over 80% of CPU utilization and losing CPU capacity. Even if just a moment,  when over threshold of utilization, broken session affinity.